# golang: convert uint32 (or any built-in type) to []byte (to be written in a file)

Tags: arrays, go, byte, unsafe

I'm trying to convert an *uint32* to a byte array (4 bytes) in Go using the **unsafe** library:

```
h := (uint32)(((fh.year*100+fh.month)*100+fh.day)*100 + fh.h)
a := make([]byte, unsafe.Sizeof(h))
copy(a, *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&h)))
```

The first two lines are correct, but then I get a runtime error ( *unexpected fault address* ) at the *copy* call.

The next step would be to call *Write*

```
_, err = fi.Write(a)
```

to write the 4 bytes into a file.

I've found other questions with a similar topic, but none with a working code. 
I'm also aware that *unsafe* is unsafe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to do it using the unsafe package?

Comment: not necessarily, but 1) I've spent some hours with this problem and I would like to know the solution, 2) I need that the file (as analyzed with an hex editor) has the uint32 without extra load, 3) the solution should work also with float32. I will write both the program that writes the file and the program that reads the file (same OS).

Comment: I see, for easy usage I would recommend the `Write` and `Read` methods of the [`binary`](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary#Write) package. Given their usage of interfaces they might have some overhead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Avoid the [unsafe](https://godoc.org/unsafe) package.

Use the [encoding/binary](http://godoc.org/encoding/binary) package to convert a `uint32` to a slice of bytes:

```
h := (uint32)(((fh.year*100+fh.month)*100+fh.day)*100 + fh.h)
a := make([]byte, 4)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(a, h)
_, err = fi.Write(a)
```

This one-liner does the same thing, but has an additional runtime cost:

```
err := binary.Write(fi, binary.LittleEndian, (uint32)(((fh.year*100+fh.month)*100+fh.day)*100 + fh.h))
```

Here's how to do the conversion with the [unsafe](https://godoc.org/unsafe) package:

```
h := (uint32)(((fh.year*100+fh.month)*100+fh.day)*100 + fh.h)
a := (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&h))[:]
_, err = fi.Write(a)
```

The expression `(*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&h))` converts a `uint32` pointer to a `[4]byte` pointer.  The `[:]` at the end creates a slice on the `[4]byte`.

The code in the question interprets the `uint32` as a [slice header](http://godoc.org/reflect#SliceHeader). The resulting slice is not valid and `copy` faults.

Comment: Is there a reason to ever use the unsafe method if the 'safe' method exists system libraries?